# Showing notication in notification center When app is Opend

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

I implement the APNS in my app . i want to show commoning notification only in notification center (at top only).

when my app is in background the notification is shows in notification center nicely. My problem is that when my app is in active (open).

**Notivication is not show in notification center . how ever i didReicievedremove ... is called .  i dont want to show any alert view my self . i just show notivication only in notification center .**

Thanks

Comment: notification display when app is in background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple really wants you to handle notifications yourself when your application is running. That's why you receive the notification within your application.

This way you can also handle it in the style of the application, without the popups from iOS itself.

Sorry, so the answer is: no you can't.

Answer (score 0):

[According Apple Push notification guidelines.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

If a notification for an application arrives when that application is not running, the device alerts the user that the application has data waiting for it.